# Why logout button does not work -shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

The logout button (actionbutton) does not work in the following script. I need to know why it is not working? and how to fix it up?

FYI: when I take out the `USER$Logged <- FALSE` from the code, the button works but I can not login anymore since the `Logged` is still `TRUE`.

Appreciate!

**ui**

```
ui2 <- function(){
        tagList(tabPanel(""),
        pageWithSidebar(
        headerPanel(
            ""
        ),
        sidebarPanel
        (
            actionButton("logout", "Logout")        
        ),
            mainPanel(tableOutput('aaa'))
        )
    )   
}


ui1 <- function(){
    tagList(h2("Hello", align = "center"),
    div(id = "login",
        wellPanel(textInput("userName", "Username"),
                  passwordInput("passwd", "Password"),
                  br(),actionButton("Login", "Log in"),
  )
}
```

**server**

```
server = (function(input, output,session) {

USER <- reactiveValues(Logged=FALSE)
observe({ 
    if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {
      if (!is.null(input$Login)) {
        if (input$Login > 0) {
            Username <- isolate(input$userName)
            Password <- isolate(input$passwd)
            query <- sprintf({"
              SELECT rowid 
              FROM users 
              WHERE username='%s' and password ='%s'"}, 
                           Username, Password, serialize=F) 
            db   <- RSQLite::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname="db.sqlite")
            user <- RSQLite::dbGetQuery(db, query) 
            RSQLite::dbDisconnect(db)
            if ( length(user$rowid)==1 ) {
              USER$Logged <- TRUE
          }
        } 
      }
    }    
})
observe({
    if (USER$Logged == FALSE)
    {
      output$page <- renderUI({div(class="outer",do.call(bootstrapPage,c("",ui1())))})
    }
    if (USER$Logged == TRUE) 
    {
      output$page <- renderUI({div(class="outer",do.call(navbarPage,c(inverse=TRUE,title = paste("Welcome", isolate(input$userName)," !"),ui2())))})
      print(ui)
    }
})
observeEvent(input$logout, {
    output$page <- renderUI({div(class="outer",do.call(bootstrapPage,c("",ui1())))})
    USER$Logged <- FALSE   
})

})
```

Generating small database:

```
library(shiny)
library(RSQLite)
setwd("E:/shiny/Correct")
db <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname="db.sqlite")
dbSendQuery(conn = db,"CREATE TABLE users (username TEXT, password TEXT, email TEXT)")
dbSendQuery(db, "INSERT INTO users ( username, password, email) VALUES ( 'ester', 'silva', 'abc@gmail.com');")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because you can't just swap between `ui` objects. What you can do instead is to create a `uiOutput` inside of `ui`, and switch between different user interfaces in runtime.

Here is a simple example of that. You could add your own logic of logging in and so on.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("ui")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  USER <- reactiveValues(Logged = FALSE)
  observe({
    if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {
      output$ui <- renderUI({
        tagList(
          h2("Hello", align = "center"),
          div(
            id = "login",
            wellPanel(
              textInput("userName", "Username"),
              passwordInput("passwd", "Password"),
              br(), actionButton("Login", "Log in")
            )
          )
        )
      })
    } else if (USER$Logged == TRUE) {
      output$ui <- renderUI({
        tagList(
          tabPanel(""),
          pageWithSidebar(
            headerPanel(
              ""
            ),
            sidebarPanel(
              actionButton("logout", "Logout")
            ),
            mainPanel(tableOutput("aaa"))
          )
        )
      })
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$Login, {
    USER$Logged <- TRUE
  })

  observeEvent(input$logout, {
    USER$Logged <- FALSE
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks @GyD for your answer and sorry for the late response. I am actually looking for an answer that does not need to combine the `ui` with the `server` part

Comment: @EsterSilva Well, it is impossible without doing it server side, because the user's logging in/out could happen in each session. Also I can't see why this is a problem.